# Ordenar por columna de relación laravel eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

Estoy intentando de ordenar de forma desc por una columna que está relacionada.
En la vista paciente estoy enviando la consulta para que me liste los pacientes y también una variable para la búsqueda, y quiero que me los liste por el orden de seguimiento esto quiere decir que me liste de primero los pacientes que tienen seguimientos.

Esta es la relación en la bd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui detallos los modelos con sus relaciones normales como inversas:

Modelo paciente

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\Sede;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class Paciente extends Model
{
   
    protected $fillable=[
        'tdoc',
        'identificacion',
        'nombres',
        'apellidos',
        'estado_civil',
        'fecha_nacimiento',
        'celular',
        'telefono',
        'correo',
        'genero',
        'estrato',
        'cargo',
        'profesion',
        'direccion',
        'barrio',
        'eps_id',
        'sede_id',
        'departamento_id',
        'municipio_id',
        'estado'
    ];

 //--------------------relaciones normales--------------
    
    //relacion uno a mucho (un paciente tiene varios seguimientos)
    public function seguimientos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Seguimiento::class);
  
    }
```

modelo seguimiento

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Seguimiento extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=[
        'id',
        'observacion',
        'fecha',
        'numero',
        'autoestima',
        'abuso_sexual',
        'orien_sexual',
        'comorbilidades',
        'diagnostico',
        'ant_psiqui',
        'prioridad',
        'paciente_id',
        'user_id',
        'problematica',
        'hijos',
        'estado',
        'cedula'
    ];

    //relacion inversa de muchos a uno (varios seguimientos pertencen a un paciente)
    public function paciente(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Paciente::class);
    }
```

He intentado de varias formas pero no me ordena la lista:

1 forma: desde el modelo paciente con la relacion le agrego el ordenamiento por id del seguimiento

```
   public function seguimientos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Seguimiento::class)->orderBy('id','desc');
  
    }
```

y en la consulta solo lo llamo con la clausula with de la relación.

```
//envio la relacion seguimientos
            $pacientes = Paciente::with(['ciudad','sede','eps','hijos','seguimientos'])
            ->where('estado','=','A')
            ->where(function($query) use($texto){
                $query->where('identificacion','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('apellidos','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('nombres','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%');
            })
            ->paginate(10);
```

y el resultado no es el esperado. en la columna opciones muestra las personas que tienen seguimiento por el botón amarillo, y debería de listar de primero a todos los pacientes con ese botón y dejar de últimos los que no tienen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2 forma: consulto con la relación de seguimiento y le agrego la funcion del ordenamiento

```
$pacientes = Paciente::with(['ciudad','sede','eps','hijos'])
            //envio la relacion con funcion para el ordenamiento
            ->with(
                    [
                        'seguimientos' => function ($q) {
                            $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
                        },
                       
                    ]
                )
            ->where('estado','=','A')
            ->where(function($query) use($texto){
                $query->where('identificacion','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('apellidos','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('nombres','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%');
            })
            ->paginate(10);
```

3 forma: agrego la clausula has pero solo me lista los pacientes que tienen seguimiento, y tambien necesito que me traiga sin seguimiento :/

```
$pacientes = Paciente::with(['ciudad','sede','eps','hijos'])
            ->where('estado','=','A')
            ->where(function($query) use($texto){
                $query->where('identificacion','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('apellidos','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('nombres','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%');
            })
            //me trae los pacientes que tienen seguimiento
            ->has('seguimientos')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: ¿de la segunda forma no te funcionó?

Comment: @gaidyjg No, el resultado fue el mismo que de la primera forma.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, puedes ordenar tu collection luego de que la obtienes, es decir, hacer `Paciente::with([... ,'seguimientos']).... ->get()->orderByDesc('seguimientos.id')`

Comment: @gaidyjg me podrias colaborar adaptándola a mi consulta, porque intento  me genera error

Comment: Lo que tu necesitas es [ordenar por subconsulta](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#subquery-ordering) amigo, creo que eso te funcionaria

Comment: pero es muy similar a su segunda forma. Lo único que se me ocurre es que añada el orderby antes del paginate para ver si le funciona.

Comment: @gaidyjg parece ser similar, pero no lo es, y la verdad lo digo con miedo a equivocarme jaja pero estoy casi seguro de que lo que tengo en mente le funcionara, analizare un poco y redacto una respuesta para ver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a un colega que su alias es erikhh9210
me dio esta solución:

con la clausula [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) Una vez obtengo como campo, luego ya puedo ordenar por esa columna

```
 $pacientes = Paciente::with(['ciudad','sede','eps','hijos'])
            ->where('estado','=','A')
            ->where(function($query) use($texto){
                $query->where('identificacion','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('apellidos','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%')
                ->orWhere('nombres','LIKE','%'.$texto.'%');
            })
            ->withCount('seguimientos')->orderByDesc('seguimientos_count')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Perfecto, estaba redactando una respuesta un poco mas larga olvidando eso jaja, ya no es necesario. Por cierto recuerda marcar tu respuesta como **Correcta** para cerrar la pregunta

Comment: @Josbert Gracias de igual forma, si me toca esperar dos días para poder aceptarla.

Comment: Muy bien..!! suerte

Answer (score 0):

Por casualidad he dado con esta manera:

- Modelo ProcesoCentro que relaciona uno a muchos Proceso con Centros

  ```
   protected $fillable =[
                   'proceso_id',
                   'centro_id',
                   'anno',
                   'responsable_id',
                   ];
   public function proceso(){
          return $this->belongsTo(Proceso::class);}
  ```
- Modelo Proceso:

  ```
    protected $fillable =[
                    'tipo_id',
                    'pcodigo',
                    'descripcion',
                    ];
  ```
- Consulta:

  $this->procesoscentros = ProcesoCentro::where('anno',$this->anno)->get();
- Tratamiento de los datos de consulta:

  @foreach ($procesoscentros->sortBy('proceso.pcodigo') as $procesocentro)
- Los Procesos de Centros se presentan ordenados por el atributo pcodigo del modelo Proceso